# A function which satisfies Laplace's Equation but is not Harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $u(z) = \text{Im}(1/z^2)$ and set $u(0) = 0$

We have that $u(z) = \text{Im}({\bar{z}^2/|z|^4)}$  and still that $u(0) = 0$

We then have that if $z \neq 0$ then $$u(z) = \frac{-2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2} $$

I want to show that all the partial derivatives of $u$ with respect to $x$ and respect to $y$ exist for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and that $\Delta u = 0$. But nonethless conclude that $u(z)$ is not Harmonic.

I'm confused on the first step because it does not appear that any partial derivative with respect to $x$ or $y$ exist for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ as this function not even continuous at $0$.  I think this is easiest to see if you convert to polar coordinates and let $r \to 0$.  So should the problem just be to show the aforementioned derivatives existing for all $z \in \mathbb{C} / \{0\}$ and that $\Delta u = 0$ for all $z \neq 0$ ?

It's more likely that I'm making a mistake than that my textbook is, so can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Is a function not defined to be harmonic whenever it satisfies Laplace's equation?

Comment: @Sobi, No.  Almost though.  It is also required that all it's second order partial derivatives exist.   Kind of a lame part of the definition, but yeah.

Comment: But how do you show that $\Delta u = 0$ if the second order partial derivatives do not exist?

Comment: @Sobi .  There are more partial derivatives of $u$ than the ones that come up in the equation $\Delta u = 0$

Comment: @Dan1618: The partial derivatives does not exist at $z=0$.

Comment: Moreover all second derivatives exist and $\partial_{xy}=\partial_{yx }$, so $u$ is harmonic.

Comment: @Dog_69 Then this is a mistake in the book, which is asking me to show that the partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ exist for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: @Dan1618: Probably. Bur whenever you understand it the rest does not matter.